# Validate File input using Yup in NextJs

Tags: next.js, yup

I have an optional file input in a yup schema and I want to validate its size and file type. The problem is that the HTML input type file is sending an array of Files to the test function, and it's messing up the schema because medicalConcernDocument should only be type File in my interface. Here's the file yup schema

```
const schema: up.ObjectSchema<PersonalDetailsFormInterface> = yup.object().shape({
    ...,
    medicalConcernDocument: yup
    .mixed<File>()
    .nullable()
    .test(
      'check-file-size',
      `File size cannot exceed ${maxFileSizeInMB}MB`,
      checkFileSize
    )
    .test(
      'check-file-type',
      `File is unsupported, supported files: ${supportedFileTypeMessage}`,
      checkFileType
    ),
});
```

checkFileSize and checkFileType are in a utility file that looks like this:

```
export function checkFileSize(files: File[] | null | undefined): boolean {
  const file = getFile(files);
  if (!file) {
    return true;
  }

  const fileSizeInBytes = file.size;
  const fileSizeInMB = Math.round(fileSizeInBytes / 1024 / 1024); 
  return (fileSizeInMB <= maxFileSizeInMB);
}

export function checkFileType(files: File[] | null | undefined): boolean {
  const file = getFile(files);
  if (!file) {
    return true;
  }

  return supportedFileTypes.includes(file.type);
}
```

Now I know I can easily have the checkFileSize/checkFileType params as files: any, and then set any as File[] like this:

```
export function checkFileSize(files: any | null | undefined): boolean {
  const file = getFile(files as File[]);
  if (!file) {
    return true;
  }
  ...
}
```

but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As I understood, your problem is that the input is an array but you want it to be only 1 item? then why not just give the item to it in the first place? and if you are forced to give the array to it, then you can use `.transform` method before tests to take the item from the array and return it for the rest of the validation

Comment: If you check the first code block I wrote, we don't trigger the checkFileSize method in the test but we pass it as an argument, so I cannot just "give the item to it in the first place"... the html input element passes an array of file objects -> yup validates whatever is on the input by sending it to our validation method e.i checkFileSize. The real issue is that if my yup property is of type mixed<File> then the validation method argument also needs to be of type File, which causes issues.

Comment: By "the first place" I meant where you want to pass the files to the schema. anyway, maybe you can use the `.transform` before `.mixed`? `.transform(files => files[0])`

Comment: ah, I get what you mean now. I wasn't aware of `.transform` in yup... I'll try it out when I can but I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for. Thanks for the clarification!